# Switching ViewController Scenes

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to present a ViewController after a button is pressed on an SKScene. How can I make this work?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let location = touch?.location(in: self) {
            let node = self.nodes(at: location)

            if node[0].name == "newGameButton" {
                let transition = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
                let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)

                self.view!.presentScene(QuestionViewController, transition: transition)

          }
      }
```

Comment: As a starting point, would be good to see how far your current code works.  So using the debugger find out: does it get as far as the first "if", the second "if" or even the presentScene line?

Comment: @Suhanda Thank you. It crashes at presentScene line.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: @Suhada please see my new post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797177/xcode-swift-skscene-transitions-once-then-crashes